# JSON Parsing sometimes crashes Swift

Tags: json, swift, swift4

I am parsing JSON in my iOS app and sometimes when the network connection is weak but isn’t gone, the app will crash while trying to parse the JSON, because it says it had an error while force unwrapping a nil.

The code I use for that is here.

```
//
//  MessageModel.swift
//  truthordare
//
//  Created by Dustin Palmatier on 11/2/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Hexham Network. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

protocol MessageModelProtocol: class {
    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}

class MessageModel: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {
    //properties

    weak var delegate: MessageModelProtocol!

    let urlPath = "Redacted" //this will be changed to the path where service.php lives

    let deleteUrl = "REDACTED"

    func downloadItems(TYPE: String, IDENTIFIER: String) {
        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "type=\(TYPE)&identifier=\(IDENTIFIER)";
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Failed to download data")
            }else {
                print("Data downloaded")
                self.parseJSON(data!)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }

    func deleteItems(TYPE: String, SKU: String) {
        let myUrl = URL(string: "https://truthordare.hexhamnetwork.com/api/92fFDd93D/erase.php");

        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

        let postString = "type=\(TYPE)&sku=\(SKU)";

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error ?? "Empty" as! Error)")
                return
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func parseJSON(_ data:Data) {

        var jsonResult = NSArray()

        do{
            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments, .mutableContainers]) as! NSArray

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)

        }

        var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
        let tables = NSMutableArray()

        for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
        {

            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

            let table = TableModel()

            //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
            if let sku = jsonElement["SKU"] as? String,
                let message = jsonElement["MESSAGE"] as? String
            {

                table.sku = sku
                table.message = message

            }

            tables.add(table)

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

            self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: tables)

        })
    }
}
```

It crashes once it gets to

```
self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: tables)
```

It says that it received a nil while force unwrapping

To initialize the delegate I called this within the classes that were calling this.

```
messageModel.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the crash reliably declare `delegate` as regular optional

```
weak var delegate: MessageModelProtocol?
```

and call it

```
self.delegate?.itemsDownloaded(items: tables)
```

In Swift 4+ it's highly recommended to use the `Codable` protocol and in any Swift version a completion handler rather than protocol / delegate.

---

And don't use `NS...` collection types in Swift at all. Use native types. And `.mutableContainers` / `.allowFragments` is pointless in Swift if the expected type is a collection type. Omit the parameter.

Comment: I define the delegate within the viewDidLoad() of the class that’s using it.

Comment: Also, its better to use `Codable` to parse JSON and avoid force unwrapping(`!`).

Comment: Nevertheless the syntax in the answer will never crash.